# obstructed conditional on preceding statement of if clause

Tags: go

I'm having trouble with an `if` statement that includes a conditional on the preceding statement part of the `if` clause.

In this simplified example, I want to extend a lookup by id to also lookup by name, with an optional prefix to be preferred.

The psuedo code is:

```
IF I have a prefix AND I can find a record using the prefix and name
THEN override the record ID
ELSE IF I can find a record using name
THEN override the record ID
ELSE do something else to override the record ID
```

In bash it would be simple:

```
if test -n "$PREFIX" && id_=$(GetByName "$PREFIX:$id")
then id="$id_"
elif id_=$(GetByName "$id")
then id="$id_"
elif id_=$(legacy_attempt "$id")
then id="$id_"
fi
```

But how to express this in go?

This is wrong:

```
if PREFIX != "" && n, err := GetByName(PREFIX + ":" + id) && err == nil {
    id = n.ID
} else if n, err := GetByName(id) && err == nil {
    id = n.ID
} else if n, err := legacy_attempt(id) && err == nil {
    id = n
}
```

I'm guessing because the middle portion of the `&&` sequence is a statement, not an expression (unlike C).

I've tried with `=` instead of `:=` and having `err` and `g` declared out of scope but it doesn't help.

I tried such horrors as:

```
if if PREFIX != "" { n, err := GetByName(PREFIX + ":" + id) } ; err == nil {
```

but the errors were more than the scoping errors of `n` and `err`, *go* claimed that it was expecting an expression after the `if` although I was trying to give it a preceding statement consisting of an if

Because of the leading conditional on `PREFIX` being non-empty I can't easily convert this if condition to use a preceding statement. I want the second half to execute if the first half doesn't execute or if the first half fails.

Are there any useful *go* idioms to help here?

I can factor the code out to be as ugly as sin*, with repeated blocks, but I'm looking for a nice idiomatic answer.

*And I mean ugly because of the two `else if` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner solution would be to define a helper function:

```
func getId(prefix string, name string) (int, error) {
    if (prefix != "") {
        if n, err := GetByName(prefix + ":" + name); err == nil {
            return n.ID, nil
        }
    }
    return GetByName(name)
}
```

and call the function as that:

```
if newId, err := getId(prefix, name) {
   id = newId
}
```

Comment: I think you need to check the variables you assign in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a single `if` statement, so use 2 of them. And you may use a "state" variable to track if the first lookup succeeds:

```
found := false
if PREFIX != "" {
    if n, err := GetByName(PREFIX + ":" + id); err == nil {
        id, found  = n.ID, true
    }
}
if !found {
    if n, err := GetByName(id); err == nil {
        id = n.ID
    }
}
```

If you create a helper function, you can make your original task more compact. Image this utility function:

```
func lookup(name string, id *string) (ok bool) {
    if n, err := GetByName(name); err == nil {
        *id = n.ID
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

With this, your original task will be:

```
_ = PREFIX != "" && lookup(PREFIX+":"+id, &id) || lookup(id, &id)
```

Correctness of the above line builds on the short-circuit evaluation of the bool logic. That is, if `PREFIX` is non-empty and the first lookup succeeds, the second lookup will not be called. If `PREFIX` is empty or the first lookup "fails", the second lookup will be called.

Even though this 2nd version is very compact, I'd still go with the first, more verbose but more clean solution. Ultimately you're goal is not to write the most compact code, but the most readable, most maintainable code.

Comment: "You can't do this with a single if statement" is a direct answer I like. But your example is not sufficient, I need to lookup the name without the prefix if there was no prefix, or if there was a prefix but a prefix name was not found.
Your examples don't fall back to lookup by name if there was a prefix but not found.
You see it starts to get ugly, especially as there is another (not shown) else case for if the name lookup also failed. I'll edit make that extra ELSE case very visible.

Comment: Yeah, it works. I wonder what idiom there is for chaining a sequence of "attempts to get a value", perhaps using an array of closures?